# byte array accessing error across projects

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, project

I have a custom type that contains a byte array per instance.
The type is serialised, and accessible by all projects in the solution.

Run time works A-Ok when calling this types use from the project it belongs too.
However when calling the runtime from an external project, the byte array looses it's data - even though the original data is right there in memory.

I've double and triple checked possible access, threading, timing errors and the problem persists.
AdditionalLy the types other sub types are perfectly accessible (string, bool ). The only difference is that, ofc the byte[] is an array.

Advice welcome.

P.s Running VS 2017 RT

Edit:
[image: Top: internal runtime, bottom external call - byte array contents is strangely empty]

Comment: I doubt it would be possible to diagnose this problem from the description that you provided. You need to show at least some code, explain what you do when you access data from another project, and tell us why you know that the data is indeed in the memory.

Comment: That's a problem as it's NDA code. I can't replicate the issue for the same reason :L. I'll try and find an alternative soon.